# "Book seats on air flights" vs. "Book seats in air flights"

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

> I rely on computers to book seats **on/in** air flights.

The answer to the above question is given as **on** but I believe it should be  **in**. Please suggest.

Answer (score 4):

**On** is correct. Probably because **on** is also the preposition for using most of the forms of transportation that you need to book space for.

See: ["In" and "on": How can I decide which one to use for vehicles?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155/in-and-on-how-can-i-decide-which-one-to-use-for-vehicles)