# "in my car" vs "on my car"

Tags: prepositions

I know that the rule is to use "in" when we are talking about small vehicles, but is there an exception when we could use "on" like for example: "I am on my car to you."? (meaning that I am on my way to someone and I am driving).

Does using "in" or "on" depend on the fact that a car is in motion or not?

Comment: I realize that the question isn't exactly the same as your question, but I think that the answers to that question will help you as well, especially this one: https://ell.stackexchange.com/a/244/

Comment: The answer to your question is "No". You can say, "I am in my car," and you can say, "I am on my way," but you **can't** say, "I am on my car" when you're in your car and on your way.