# Which preposition is correct "On the airplane" or "In the airplane"?

Tags: prepositions

Which preposition I have to use when talking about "airplane" or "aircraft"?

Should I use "**in**" like "in the car" or "**on**" like "on the bus?

> "**On** the airplane / aircraft"

or

> "**In** the airplane / aircraft"?

Comment: [George Carlin had a joke about this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QxlE32ikHzo). In English we get "on" the plane, but it really means to get "in" the plane. [Our Magnificent Bastard Tongue](https://www.amazon.com/Our-Magnificent-Bastard-Tongue-History/dp/1592404944) at work.

Comment: Last time I flew, I was **on** the airplane, but my luggage was **in** the airplane. [**Related question**](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155/in-and-on-how-can-i-decide-which-one-to-use-for-vehicles).

Comment: @Rob Telling someone who is not sure whether to use *on* or *in* that "'on' really means 'in'" doesn't strike me as being helpful :)

Comment: @Jim: Comments are addressed to the readership at large, not just the OP. That said, I think any correct information should prove useful to questioners here. This isn't a fourth-grade classroom, after all.

Comment: @Rob In the context, on does not "really mean" in.What is correct is that there are many meanings of *on.*

Comment: Most likely you'll go your way (and I'll go mine).

Answer (score 1):

When you board you get *on* (or *on to*, or *on board*) the plane; however while you are airborne, I certainly hope you are riding *in* the plane.  These quirky English prepositions are the source of much humor, as with the George Carlin joke in Robusto's comment.

As with ships, boats, buses, and trucks, in general it's better to use *on* when referring to airplanes:

> OK, I have to hang up.  I'm running late to get **on** the plane.
>
> Please refrain from smoking while **on board** the aircraft.

*In* is used when referring to the actual position of objects within the aircraft.

> Although the primary systems are not expected to fail, there are two backups located **in** the tail section of the aircraft.
>
> I got lucky -- I had only an economy ticket but the airline overbooked so they ended up seating me **in** first class.

Answer (score 1):

In or on an aircraft (plane). The answer to whether it is in or on is: that depends.

- We are **flying or traveling on an Airbus or flying on a 747**. For a type of plane where you are a passenger. In short, **you fly on a plane**, which is funny, because it similar to: riding on a horse.

Please note: one also **travels on** a **train** or on a **boat** or on a **bus** or on a **bicycle or motorcycle**. **on** is used to mean: on board a plane, boat, bus, or other means of transport. 
- He was on the bus when I saw him.
- He was on his bicycle when we ran into him.

Naturally, with modes of transport that require boarding (planes, boats, trains, buses), you can also be **in it** as opposed to being outside of it if that requires clarification in some particular context.

**One travels on a means of transportation** or, of course, by x.

**EXCEPTION** to ON, and it is a big one:

**One travels in a car or taxi, or one rides in a car or taxi**.

all of these things can be **by**: to **travel by car, plane, train, bus, bicycle,** etc.

Also bear in mind how an ambiguity might arise:

Q:  **Where did you see the bad guy**, John?

A: I saw him **on the plane** just now.

Q: What? **Where was he sitting during the flight**? What seat?

A: No, no, you don't get it. I saw him on the plane, standing on a wing outside the emergency exit.

_