# "Transport something on a sprinter van" or "transport something with a sprinter van"?

Tags: prepositions

Could you please tell me which preposition, *on* or *with*, it is more natural and correct to use in the context below?

> The load is not to heavy, so we could transport it **on**/**with** a sprinter van.

Comment: Either preposition is fine. Or you could have ***by, in,*** or ***using***, and probably several other alternatives.

Comment: Generally, things are transported **in** vans and not "on" them. Of course, then, they are also being transported by van and not by car. I would not use with. I would move furniture **with** a van, not a car.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*With* is fine, but *in* is also valid. *With* is used to refer to methods or tools, which would include the van. *In* is used for riding inside a car, van, truck, etc, and for carrying something inside such a vehicle. With a person you would say *they travelled in a van*. *With* would be more natural if you needed to make multiple journeys or if the amount is uncertain - *The firm makes deliveries with a sprinter van* - while *in* is more likely to refer to a single load.

You can also say *transport it by sprinter van* which refers to the mode of transport. Note that there is no article *a* here, because you're talking about the type of vehicle.

*On* is normally used with public transport - *on a bus*, *on a train* - or something you ride on top of, such as *on a bicycle*.

There is an existing question but it refers to people, not cargo: ["In" and "on": How can I decide which one to use for vehicles?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/155/in-and-on-how-can-i-decide-which-one-to-use-for-vehicles)

Comment: "On" would be possible if the thing was too large to fit "in" the van and had to be lashed to the roof. But that's the only case where you could use "on."

Comment: "with" really does not work with transport here.